# Inserting Strings into an ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, indexing, junit

I created two methods to insert generics data into an ArrayList:

```
public void add(T element) throws SortingException{
    if(element == null)
      throw new SortingException("addElement: element can't be null");

    int index = getIndexInsert(element);

    (this.array).add(index, element);
  }



private int getIndexInsert(T element){
    int index = 0;
    boolean cont = true;
    T currEl = null;
    while((index<(this.array).size())&&cont){
           currEl = (this.array).get(index);
           if((this.comparator).compare(element, currEl)<0)
               cont = false;
           else index++;
        }//while

    return index;
  }
```

Now, if I test these methods with a String type I got this error:

```
testStringOrder(sorting.SortingTests): null
```

This is my testing method:

```
@Test
  public void testStringOrder() throws SortingException {
    String[] arrExpected = {"ciao","come","stai"};
    String[] arrActual = new String[3];
    arrayString.add("come");
    arrayString.add("ciao");
    arrayString.add("stai");
    arrayString=arrayString.insertionSort(0);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
      /*DEBUG:*/ System.out.println(arrayString.get(i));
      arrActual[i] = arrayString.get(i);
    }
    assertArrayEquals(arrExpected,arrActual);
  }
```

It stops working as soon as I try to invoke the first add. I don't know if the problem is the String type, because I tested it with two arrays of Integer and it works. The arrayString is declared here:

```
  private Sorting<Integer> arrayInteger;
  private Sorting<String> arrayString;

  @Before
  public void createArrayOfInteger(){
    arrayInteger = new Sorting<>(new IntegerComparator());
  }

  public void createArrayOfString(){
    arrayString = new Sorting<>(new StringComparator());
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us where `arrayString` is initialised?

Comment: I added that part.

Comment: You probably need `@Before` on the `createArrayOfString()` method as well.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks, I totally forgot it. Now it works!